# Google cloud speech very inaccurate and misses words on clean audio

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I am using Google cloud speech through Python and finding many transcriptions are inaccurate and missing several words. This is a simple script I'm using to return a transcript of an audio file, in this case 'out307.wav':

```
client = speech.SpeechClient()

with io.open('out307.wav', 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()

audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
    enable_word_time_offsets=True,
    language_code='en-US',
    audio_channel_count=1)

response = client.recognize(config, audio)

for result in response.results:
    alternative = result.alternatives[0]
    print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
```

This returns the following transcript:

> to do this the tensions and suspicions except

This is very far off what the actual audio says (I've uploaded it at https://vocaroo.com/i/s1zdZ0SOH1Ki). The audio is a .wav and very clear with no background noise. This is worse than average, as in some cases it will get the transcription fully correct on a 10 second audio file, or it may miss just a couple of words. Is there anything I can do to improve results?

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, I tried your audio file with your code and I get the same result, but, if I change the language_code to "en-UK" I am able to get the full response.

I'm working for Google Cloud and I created for you a public issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/120064953), you can track there the updates.